# JAVA creating objects

Tags: java

I'm a beginner at Java and object creation is really confusing me...

I have this class, that have objects of another class with 2 constructors.

```
public class Instructor{

     private Name name;
     private Date started;

     public Instructor(Name name, Date started){
         if(name != null){
            this.name = name;
         }
          else{
             this.name = new Name();
         }

         if(started != null){
            this.started = started;
         }
         else{
           this.started = new Date();
         }

       }
```

I'm trying to call my constructor second constructor in my Instructor class with these following parameters.

```
public class Course
{
    private Instructor instructor;
    private Date start;
    private Date end;
    private int number;
    private String title;
    private String department;


    public Course(Instructor instructor, Date start, Date end, 
                      int number, String title, String department){
        this.instructor = new Instructor(name);
        this.instructor = new Instructor(start);
   }
 }
```

How do I call constructor 2 of my instructor class ? I tried everything I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Objects are really confusing me.

Comment: Is this the whole source code? I do not see and 2nd constructor

Comment: The first constructor is just a default.  public Instructor(){
this.name = new Name();

Comment: Then it is what the answers suggest, you need to call the constructor with the arguments specified. So either none or 2.

Comment: There is NO second constructor in the class Instructor. There's only one.

Comment: If you add a constructor to your class the default constructor will be the constructor you made. there's not gonna be a no param constructor anymore. Right now there's only one constructor and only

Comment: If you have a constructor `public Instructor(Name name, Date started)` you call it with `new Instructor(someName, someDate)`. If the constructor is `public Instructor(int i, String s, Object o, Date d)` you call it with `new Instructor(someInt, someString, someObject, someDate)`, simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

As per your constructor in Instructor you should initialize it with:

```
this.instructor = new Instructor(name, start);
```

Look at the constructor signature of Instructor:

```
public Instructor(Name name, Date started)
```

So you should initialize a new Instructor object by those two properties.